# Need to have Highcharts render each category on a separate axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is a link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates what I would like.  I would like to keep the series to Joe, Jan and John, so that I can exclude or include their data by clicking on the series.  As you can see their consumption of apples is so much higher that the the other categories look ridiculous.  How can this be accomplished with highcharts.  http://jsfiddle.net/rstelow/m4U6s/3/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked bar chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [125, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [90, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [100, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit better with the stacking off.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ry5AJ/

```
 plotOptions: {

        },
```

I'm not sure what more you can do, that data is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use logarithmic axis for yAxis

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'lagarithmic'
}
```

note: min for logarithmic axis is always greater than 0.

here I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/m4U6s/4/).

Hope this makes it look better.

Answer (score 0):

Split series into smaller one, then you can set each category for different axis. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4U6s/5/

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        opposite: true,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
    }, {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'john',
        color: colors[0],
        name: 'John',
        data: [
            [0, 125]
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'jane',
        color: colors[1],
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [
            [0, 90]
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'joe',
        color: colors[2],
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [
            [0, 100]
        ]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        color: colors[0],
        linkedTo: 'john',
        name: 'John',
        data: [
            [1, 3]
        ]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        color: colors[1],
        linkedTo: 'jane',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [
            [1, 2]
        ]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        color: colors[2],
        linkedTo: 'joe',
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [
            [1, 4]
        ]
    }]
});
```